# .htaccess mod_rewrite URL query

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I was hoping someone could help me out. I'm building a CRM application and need help modifying the .htaccess file to clean up the URLs. I've read every post regarding .htaccess and mod_rewrite and I've even tried using http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ to obtain the results with no success. Here is what I am attempting to do.

- Let's call the base URL www.domain.com
- We are using php with a mysql back-end and some jQuery and javascript
- In that "root" folder is my .htaccess file. I'm not sure if I need a .htaccess file in each subdirectory or if one in the root is enough.
- We have several actual directories of files including "crm", "sales", "finance", etc.
- First off we want to strip off all the ".php" extensions which I am able to do myself thanks to these posts. However, the querying of the company and contact IDs are where I am stuck.
- Right now if I load www.domain.com/crm/companies.php it displays all the companies in a list.
- If I click on one of the companies it uses javascript to call a "goto_company(x)" jQuery script that writes a form and submit that form based on the ID (x) of the company. This works fine and keeps the links clean as all the end user sees is www.domain.com/crm/company.php. However you can't navigate directly to a company.
- So we added a few lines in PHP to see if the POST is null and try a GET instead allowing us to do www.domain.com/crm/company.php?companyID=40 which displays company #40 out of the database.
- I need to rewrite this link, and all other associated links to www.domain.com/crm/company/40
- I've tried everything and nothing seems to work.  Keep in mind that I need to do this for "contacts" and also on the sales portion of the app will need to do something for "deals".

To summarize here's what I am looking to do:

1. Change www.domain.com/crm/dash.php to www.domain.com/crm/dash
2. Change www.domain.com/crm/company.php?companyID=40 to www.domain.com/crm/company/40
3. Change www.domain.com/crm/contact.php?contactID=27 to www.domain.com/crm/contact/27
4. Change www.domain.com/sales/dash.php to www.domain.com/sales/dash
5. Change www.domain.com/sales/deal.php?dealID=6 to www.domain.com/sales/deal/6

(40, 27, and 6 are just arbitrary numbers as examples)

Just for reference, when I used the generateit.net/mod-rewrite site using www.domain.com/crm/company.php?companyID=40 as an example, here is what it told me to put in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^crm/company/([^/]*)$ /crm/company.php?companyID=$1 [L]
```

Needless to say that didn't work.

**OK here is an updated based on the help received from Gohn67 below**

It is working with the exception of a small bug I can't seem to figure out.  I have created the .htaccess file in the "crm" directory. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/([\d]+)$ /crm/company.php?companyID=$1 [L]
```

This rewrites www.domain.com/test/40 to www.domain.com/crm/company.php?companyID=40 so it's very close to what I need.

The bug is that I cannot replace "test" with the word "company" in my RewriteRule. I do not know why. I can put anything but the word "company" in there; even the names of other PHP files in the "crm" directory such as "contact" or "add-contact".  As a further test I actually renamed company.php to test.php and changed the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([\d]+)$ /crm/test.php?companyID=$1 [L]
```

which worked.

Comment: What happens if you replace `^crm/company/([^/]*)$` with `^/crm/company/([^/]*)$`?

Comment: I tried adding a "/" as you described above but 1) that doesn't change anything, and 2) I read a post that stated the "/" needed to be removed as it is implied. I'm a super-novice when it comes to this .htaccess business so I'm not sure which way is right and which was is wrong. All I know is neither way works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the generated rewrite looks kind of strange there. I'm not sure what it is trying to match here `([^/]*)`.

Here is an example that may work for you. I tested these on my system.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^crm/dash/?$ /crm/dash.php [L]
RewriteRule ^crm/company/([\d]+)/?$ /crm/company.php?companyID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^crm/contact/([\d]+)/?$ /crm/contact.php?contactID=$1 [L]
```

This is only a few of your routes as an example. I admit that they could be more robust though, because doing this way will lead to a lot of rewrite rules, some of which you could elminate with better regex patterns. But hopefully this gets you started.

Here are some updated rewrite rules taking into consideration a subdirectory. It also fixes a a mistake from above:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crm
RewriteRule ^dash/?$ dash.php [L]
RewriteRule ^company/([\d]+)/?$ company.php?companyID=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/([\d]+)/?$ contact.php?contactID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your example above worked but I ended up tweaking one thing; I created the .htaccess file in the "crm" directory and removed the "crm/" prefix from the rule so it reads:

`code` RewriteRule ^company/([\d]+)(/)$ /crm/company.php?companyID=$1 [L] `code`
Essentially when I request http://www.domain.com/crm/yeah/40/ it redirects me properly to http://www.domain.com/crm/company.php?companyID=40.
I also can't use "company" as the requesting URI. Not sure why but I had to change it to "hello" as a test.

Comment: Hmm, I think if you put the htacess in the crm directory you will need to add the RewriteBase directory, so you'd add `RewriteBase /crm` after `RewriteEngine On`. I'm going to test it out now, but that is the general way to do it.

Comment: So here's one last thing. All my file links to CSS and Scripts are now screwed up. Should I just make them full URLs so instead of ../css/core.css just make it http://www.domain.com/css/core.css? Is that the acceptable method?

Comment: Yeah, what I'd do with the css is have a configuration file that sets your style, script, asset paths. Then you can use that to print your base url for your css. You can also hard code the value using /css/core.css. If you add the forward slash at the beginning it will look at the root of the domain. But it's not a good idea to hardcode those values.

Comment: So why do you think I can't use the word "company"? Is it because it is an existing file name in the directory and "test" is not? Just for testing purposes my code reads `RewriteRule ^test/([\d]+)$ /crm/company.php?companyID=$1 [L]` Do I need a RewriteCond above it to test for it being a file?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case since the url you are using is company/ and not company.php, so maybe you can post what url you're currently trying to access and your current rewrite rules. I tried to move this discussion to chat, but you don't have enough points unfortunately.

Comment: Yes it is working but not 100% as intended. I can type http://www.domain.com/crm/test/40 but I cannot type http://www.domain.com/crm/company/40. I can use any word in my RewriteRule other than "company" in lieu of "test" so my code right now literally reads `RewriteRule ^test/([\d]+)$ /crm/company.php?companyID=$1 [L]`. I can only deduct that it is because company.php is an actual file.

Comment: Can you post your current rewrite rules in your question. Maybe I can debug it for you. It shouldn't matter if you have a file named company.php there since you aren't specifying company.php in your url.

Comment: You should look at my edited answer. See the second version. There is a RewriteBase /crm, that should work, unless I misunderstand your question. You want to go to http:/domain.com/crm/company/40?

Comment: Nope, adding the RewriteBase and changing the RewriteRules as you've specified doesn't work.  It only works the way I have it in my updated post. Also, in my updated post whether I add a RewriteBase or not it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hmm, does it work with the .htaccess file at the root directory instead of in crm?

Comment: If I put it in the root, remove the `RewriteBase /crm` and add back in the `crm/` to the code it works as described in my update. It still won't allow me to  use the word "company".

Comment: It does the same thing if I try it in the Sales directory with deal.php. I can't call deal/40 because it has the same name as the file. It's not a big deal. I'm just going to rename all the php files. It's close enough!